# Probability Of Choosing A Function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, functions

This question is not from any of my textbooks, and perhaps it's not original either, but it is a question that came to my mind.

Given two functions: $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x + 5$, what is the probability that the next function we choose is such that, if $c(x)$ be that function, then $g(z) \le c(z) \le f(z)$ for all values of $z$. That is to say, $c(x)$ is a function that "is between" the two function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I don't know if the problem proposed has a solution, however, it intuitively seems like a possible question. The thing is that both functions are continuous, that is, they take on every real value.

The problem might be equivalent to asking: if I pick a real number between 1 and 10, what is the probability that the number is 4.5? Is there no resolution to such a question? If not, why? I do not know how to approach this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe that both problem statements are equivalent (I believe functions in the plane have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not entirely sure). The answer to the security and is a firm $0$, either in the teals or in the rationals. There are an infinite number of either between 1 and 10. You can consider the probability of picking a number in the *interval* $[3,5]$, for example, but not a single number. I believe the first problem is also $0$, as I can write uncountably many functions *not* between those two.

Comment: I don't think their quite equivalent after reflecting on it. I think the first problem statement might be the same as "what is the probability of choosing a number between $4-6$ from a range of $0-9$", which would be $6–4\over 9–0$$= 40\%$. However, it's more of a problem of areas; although not exactly. It doesn't seem intuitive for it to be a $0$ to me, however.

Comment: Consider: any line $y=mx+b$ with $m \ne 1$ crosses both lines. There are uncountably many real $m,b$ that we could choose. All other polynomials other than $y=x+b, 0<b<5$ cross both lines. There are uncountably many of those lines, as well as other functions (one of those lines plus a periodic function with no poles, or plus a sigmoid function), but those are a small subset. I can't prove they have density zero among all possible real functions... but I'm not sure there are *any* dense subsets to be had here.

Comment: What do you think it means to choose a function at random?  (Or a real number, for that matter.)

Comment: @EricSnyder the cardinality of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself is much larger than the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, the set of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \{0, 1\}$ is in natural bijection with the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JBL I don't think I can speak of "choice" beyond the scope of informality. I think the answer to my question lies in the answer of: given a circle inscribed in a square; and say at random that we choose another circle of any radius. What is the probability that the second circle so chosen lies wholy within the first circle? The problem is that there are infinitely many positions to choose from, and infinitely many radii that the second circle could take on.

Comment: Some sets (say, finite sets or intervals of real numbers) have a natural *uniform distribution* with respect to which one can say "draw an element uniformly at random" and mean roughly what your intuition tells you.  None of the sets you're talking about have this, so to say the words "draw one at random" you need to explain what the probability distribution is.  (Basically, I think it is not possible to make sense of your question on a purely naive basis.)

Comment: @JBL Thanks for that info, but do we even have a name for the cardinality of the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$? I feel like we're still a bit hazy even on $\aleph_1$... Edit: Oh, I see, the cardinality is $\beth_2$.